# how do you covert a number 1 - 100 to a number -96 to 0

Tags: python

ok so I am trying to make a volume knob with Arduino and python, Arduino handles the rotary encoder and python handles the volume change. I am using the library pycaw to change the volume. I am stuck because I have a number, 1-100 coming from Arduino but i need a number -96 to 0 for pycaw. Does anyone know of a library that can help me? Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338698/p5-js-map-function-in-python

Comment: this is the code i put in OldRange = 100
                                      NewRange = 96
                                      NewValue = (((dat - 0) * NewRange) / OldRange) + -96 but i get the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'